# How to write helper / decorator function for cdk function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I have below function which will create S3 bucket with cdk code:

```
    def __create_s3_components_bucket(self, this_dir: str, props):
    """Create S3 components bucket"""

    s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(
        self,
        "BucketForImageBuilder",
        bucket_name="some_bucket_name_1234",
        block_public_access=s3.BlockPublicAccess(
            block_public_acls=True,
            block_public_policy=True,
            ignore_public_acls=True,
            restrict_public_buckets=True,
        ),
        public_read_access=False,
        encryption=s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
        removal_policy=cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        auto_delete_objects=True,
        lifecycle_rules=[
            s3.LifecycleRule(
                abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_after=cdk.Duration.days(amount=2),
                enabled=True,
                expiration=cdk.Duration.days(amount=180),
                transitions=[
                    s3.Transition(
                        transition_after=cdk.Duration.days(amount=30),
                        storage_class=s3.StorageClass.ONE_ZONE_INFREQUENT_ACCESS,
                    )
                ],
            )
        ],
    )
```

I would like to create helper / decorator function to implement this part of above code for all buckets defined in different stacks:

```
            block_public_access=s3.BlockPublicAccess(
            block_public_acls=True,
            block_public_policy=True,
            ignore_public_acls=True,
            restrict_public_buckets=True,
```

I understand theory (watched few YouTube videos, read some examples) that they add extra functionality, etc., but can't get my head around of doing that in this example. Is it doable? If yes, how? Can anyone share some code example please?

Answer (score 0):

so you can do something like:

`my_bucket = create_s3_bucket(self, "MyBucketName")`

if so, and you stated you want this helper function to be used for different stacks, then you will want to do something like the following in your utility/helper file (using Python)

```
from aws_cdk import aws_s3
def create_s3_bucket(scope, bucket_name:str) -> aws_s3.Bucket:
    return aws_s3.Bucket(
        scope, bucket_name,
        bucket_name=bucket_name,
        property1= value1,
        ect = ect
        )
```

if you want do more things with that bucket you can do so, just do so before the return, or create the bucket as its own object than manipulate it as you need before returning it.

Two things to note: if your function to do this commonality is NOT in the same stack class then you MUST pass it the self parameter as scope - the scope of a construct is how CDK knows what stack to put that constructs instructions for formation into. So, as you may have noticed, every construct in the **init** of a Stack starts with self, "LogicalID" - these are the two cloudformation template variables needed to allow CloudFormation to actually work - the first defining the stack this instruction goes into, the second the LogicalID of that cloudformation resource (how CloudFormation identifies a resource that the stack controls, and when to update or create a new one.

So since you stated you intend to use this across multiple stacks, put this into its own helper/utility file and import it, then pass it the self variable when called so CDK knows which stack its part of.

Second, you should return the object. Even if you don't plan on using it now, its better to return it so you can make use of it later. To reference the Bucket.BucketName or to add a role to it thats unique for that stack or whatever.

You can also add additional parameters to the function for anything you want to specify, and set a default. For instance:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_s3
def create_s3_bucket(scope, bucket_name:str, removal: cdk.RemovalPolicy = cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN) -> aws_s3.Bucket
    return aws_s3.Bucket(scope, bucket_name
       ...
       removal_policy=removal)
```

I'm not 100% confident in decorator functions, but I am pretty sure that the way CDK construct instantiators work a decorator would not do what you are trying to do here, where this does. This is mostly because most properties cannot be set *after* the bucket is instantiated in your code. The few that could be could be put in a decorator, I suppose, something like

*psudo code*

```
def custom_s3_decorator():
    yield
    bucket.add_removal_policy(blah)
    bucket.add_to_principle_policy(blah)
```

ect, with the correct code needed to make a decorator work, but again ... pretty sure most of what you want isn't possible to do after the instatiation so you'd want to use a helper function.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, will try this, but now my whole idea seems like over engineering :)

Comment: hah! it depends on how much you are reusing. For instance, in my project we have something like 25 lambdas. I have a helper function for creating lambdas in any stack, so they all use the same version of Python, the same time out, ect (with the ability to override if i want!) and they all get the same retention role (delete in dev, retain in prod) automatically - and If we, for instance, move from python 3.7 to 3.8 i only had to update it in one location. Thats where this is useful. But it is a use case thing!

Comment: Well yes sure, but we have Aspects in cdk to handle that also :), thx again !